# Laravel 5: Updatable List|Table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to create an "updatable" order list|table where the user can change one dropdown value of the list to "take in charge" all orders listed.

*(PS: user will also have the possibility to filter the list in order to take in charge only specific orders | order-row checkboxes will be removed since not necessary).*

I have created my controller (using not Eloquent but query builder to query the data).

I'm passing my data to my view.

I can view the expected records in the list|table.

User can choose his name into the first order row dropdown called "Prise en charge", then all other order rows dropdowns values are changed accordingly :

https://www.screencast.com/t/Ei1wdJtb
*(link works with Mozilla and Chrome but not Opera)*

Now I would like to update with submit all in the table listed orders.

I know how to create CRUDs, but I never created this kind of hybrids, so it is a little bit unclear (or completely honestly said) how to do it.

I would appreciate some expertise about what is missing to submit and update accordingly the database table columns.

**CONTROLLER**

```php
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Session;
use Request;
use DB;
use CRUDBooster;
Use SoftDelete;

class AdminLaboOrdersManagementController extends Controller {

    public function updateOrder(Request $request) {

        # QUERIES
        # I haven't printed the queries since it is not relevant I guess and
        # because it takes a lot of space. If needed I will of course provide ...

        # SEND TO VIEW
        return view('labo_orders_mgt_view_index', 
            compact('staffs','orders','statusorders'));
    }
}
```

**BLADE**
**Structure**

*row-id is the row id of the order into the table*

```php
<div class="order" row-id="1029">rows and data</div>
<div class="order" row-id="1039">rows and data</div>
<div class="order" row-id="1049">rows and data</div>
<div class="order" row-id="1059">rows and data</div>
<div class="order" row-id="1060">rows and data</div>
<div class="order" row-id="1062">rows and data</div>
```

**Code**

```php
@extends('crudbooster::admin_template')

@section('content')

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/laboratory/takeCareOf.js')}}"></script>

    <table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>

        <tbody>

            {{--dd($staffs)--}}
            {{--dd($orders)--}}

            <!-- FOREACH LOOP TO DISPLAY THE ORDERS -->

            <form method="POST" action="" id="takecareof">

                <div class='row button'>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnFront" style="cursor: pointer;font-size:24px; height:47px;width:100%;"> Je confirme la prise en charge </button>

                </div>

                @foreach($orders as $order)

                        <div class="order" row-id="{{$order->rowID}}">

                            <div class="col-md-1 sub_chkbox">

                                <input type="checkbox" class="sub_chk" data-id="{{$order->rowID}}">

                            </div>

                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-2 takecareof">

                                    <h5>Prise en charge par</h5>

                                    <p>

                                        <select name="dropdownlabostaffs" class="dropdownlabostaffs form-control">

                                            @if (isset($staffs))

                                                <option value="">Artisans</option>

                                                    @foreach ($staffs as $staff)

                                                        <option value="{{ $staff->staffID }}"{{ $staff->staffID == $order->ownerID ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $staff->staffName }}</option>

                                                    @endforeach

                                            @endif

                                        </select>

                                    </p>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                             @if($order->FirstnameUser === NULL || $order->LastnameUser === NULL)

                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-md-2 ordernr">
                                        <h5>Commande no</h5>
                                        <p>
                                            {{ $order->orderID }}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3 orderby">
                                        <h5>Commandé par</h5>
                                        <p>
                                            @if(isset($order->FirstnameUser)) {{ $order->FirstnameUser }} @endif @if(isset($order->LastnameUser)) {{ $order->LastnameUser }} @endif 
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3 forcustomer">
                                        <h5>Pour Client</h5>
                                        <p>
                                            @if(isset($order->FirstnameCustomer)) {{ $order->FirstnameCustomer }} @endif @if(isset($order->LastnameCustomer)) {{ $order->LastnameCustomer }} @endif
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3 laboratory">
                                        <h5>Laboratoire</h5>
                                        <p>
                                            {{ $order->Laboratory }}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            @else

                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-md-2 ordernr">
                                        <h5>Commande no</h5>
                                        <p>
                                            {{ $order->orderID }}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3 orderby">
                                        <h5>Commandé par</h5>
                                        <p>
                                            @if(isset($order->FirstnameUser)) {{ $order->FirstnameUser }} @endif @if(isset($order->LastnameUser)) {{ $order->LastnameUser }} @endif
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3 forcustomer">
                                        <h5>Pour Client</h5>
                                        <p>
                                            @if(isset($order->FirstnameCustomer)) {{ $order->FirstnameCustomer }} @endif @if(isset($order->LastnameCustomer)) {{ $order->LastnameCustomer }} @endif
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3 laboratory">
                                        <h5>Laboratoire</h5>
                                        <p>
                                            {{ $order->Laboratory }}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            @endif

                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-6 status">

                                    <h5>Statut</h5>

                                    <p>

                                        <select name="statusorder" class="statusorder form-control">

                                            @if (isset($statusorders))

                                                <option value="">Status</option>

                                                    @foreach ($statusorders as $statusorder)

                                                        <option value="{{ $statusorder->statusorderID }}"{{ $statusorder->statusorderID == $order->StatusID ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $statusorder->statusorderName }}</option>

                                                    @endforeach

                                            @endif

                                        </select>

                                    </p>

                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 pickup">
                                    <h5>Date | heure de retrait</h5>
                                    <p>
                                    {{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($order->{'DeliveryDate'})) }} | 13:15
                                    </p>
                                    <p>

                                    </p>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-2 category">
                                    <h5>Catégorie</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        @if(isset($order->Type)) {{ $order->Type }} @endif
                                    </p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2 product">
                                    <h5>Produit</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        @if(isset($order->Name)) {{ $order->Name }} @endif
                                    </p>
                                </div>

                                @if($order->Type === 'Gâteaux' || $order->Type === 'Tarte' || $order->Type === 'Tarte-fine')

                                    <div class="col-md-2 servings">
                                        <h5># Personnes</h5>
                                        <p>
                                            @if(isset($order->Servings)) {{ $order->Servings }} @endif
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                @endif

                                @if($order->Type === 'Gâteaux' || $order->Type === 'Tarte' || $order->Type === 'Tarte-fine')

                                    <div class="col-md-2 chocodeco">
                                        <h5>Déco Choco</h5>

                                        @if(strpos($order->DecoChocoFruits, 'souhaitée') !== false)
                                        <p>Oui</p>
                                        @else
                                        <p>Non</p>
                                        @endif

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4 flowerdeco">

                                        <h5>Déco Fleurs</h5>

                                        @if(strpos($order->DecoSmallFlowers, 'souhaitée') !== false)
                                        <p>Oui</p>
                                        @else
                                        <p>Non</p>
                                        @endif

                                    </div>

                                @endif

                                @if($order->Type === 'Pain-surprise')

                                    <div class="col-md-2 weight">
                                        <h5>Poids</h5>
                                        <p>
                                            @if(isset($order->Weight)) {{ $order->Weight }} @endif
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4 colorribbon">
                                        <h5>
                                        Couleur Ruban
                                        </h5>
                                        <p>
                                            @if(isset($order->RibbonColor)) {{ $order->RibbonColor }} @endif
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                @endif

                                @if($order->Type === 'Pain')

                                    <div class="col-md-2 breadquantity">
                                        <h5>
                                        Quantité
                                        </h5>
                                        <p>
                                            @if(isset($order->BreadQuantity)) {{ $order->BreadQuantity }} @endif
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-6 slicecut">
                                        <h5>
                                        Coupe
                                        </h5>

                                        @if(strpos($order->Cut, 'souhaitée') !== false)
                                        <p>Oui</p>
                                        @else
                                        <p>Non</p>
                                        @endif

                                    </div>

                                @endif

                                @if($order->Type === 'Salé')

                                    <div class="col-md-2 savouryquantity">
                                        <h5>
                                        Quantité
                                        </h5>
                                        <p>
                                            @if(isset($order->SavouryQuantity)) {{ $order->SavouryQuantity }} @endif
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-6 savouryassortment">
                                        <h5>
                                        Assortiment
                                        </h5>
                                        <p>
                                            @if(isset($order->CanapésAssortment)) {{ $order->CanapésAssortment }} @endif
                                            @if(isset($order->MiniPuffsAssortment)) {{ $order->MiniPuffsAssortment }} @endif
                                            @if(isset($order->VolsAuVentAssortment)) {{ $order->VolsAuVentAssortment }} @endif
                                            @if(isset($order->AppetisersAssortment)) {{ $order->AppetisersAssortment }} @endif
                                        </p>

                                    </div>

                                @endif

                                @if($order->Type === 'Sucré')

                                    <div class="col-md-2 sweetquantity">
                                        <h5>
                                        Quantité
                                        </h5>
                                        <p>
                                            @if(isset($order->SweetQuantity)) {{ $order->SweetQuantity }} @endif
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-6 sweetassortment">
                                        <h5>
                                        Coupe
                                        </h5>
                                        <p>
                                            @if(isset($order->SweetAssortment)) {{ $order->SweetAssortment }} @endif
                                        </p>

                                    </div>

                                @endif

                            </div>

                            <div class="row">

                                    @if($order->Type === 'Pain-surprise')

                                        <div class="col-md-3 variante1">
                                            <h5>
                                            Assortiment 1
                                            </h5>
                                            <p>
                                                @if(isset($order->Assortment1)) {{ $order->Assortment1 }} @endif
                                            </p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-3 variante2">
                                            <h5>
                                            Assortiment 2
                                            </h5>
                                            <p>
                                                @if(isset($order->Assortment2)) {{ $order->Assortment2 }} @endif
                                            </p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-3 variante3">
                                            <h5>
                                            Assortiment 3
                                            </h5>
                                            <p>
                                                @if(isset($order->Assortment3)) {{ $order->Assortment3 }} @endif
                                            </p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-3 variante4">
                                            <h5>
                                            Assortiment 4
                                            </h5>
                                            <p>
                                                @if(isset($order->Assortment4)) {{ $order->Assortment4 }} @endif
                                            </p>
                                        </div>

                                    @endif

                            </div>

                        </div>

                @endforeach

            </form>

        </tbody>

    </table>

<!-- ADD A PAGINATION -->
<p></p>
@endsection
```